# Excel calculate the difference between times and highlight with conditional formatting

Tags: excel

I have a time sheet and I need to calculate the difference between two time values. As this sheet will be made available to all employees, I cannot make use of the 1904 date system hence I resolved to using this

```
=IF(A1-B1<0, "-" & TEXT(ABS(A1-B1),"hh:mm"), A1-B1)
```

This works and gives a negative sign to the negative values thereby overcoming the hashes ####### problem and display in Excel 2007 and higher.

Yet I cannot create conditional formatting to the result as it is obvious that the values are interpreted as text and neither can I count a group of these values with a simple summation.

Edit 1

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use conditional formatting.

For your formula:

```
C1:  =ABS(A1-B1)
```

For your Conditional Formatting formula:

```
=A1<B1
```

[image]

If you also want to have a negative sign (or parentheses) around the value, you can also go to the Number tab of the conditional formatting format dialog box, and enter an appropriate string in the positive number field.

[image]

Be careful as the values in Column C will always be positive, so do not use them in subsequent calculations.  Use the original values in A1:B1 to determine whether to add or subtract

Comment: Ron, I did implement your suggestions and conditional formatting worked both in the negative and the positive values. Yet I cannot overcome the monthly calculation see Edit 1. The formula used is =ABS(L8:L9)-(M8:M9) for the totals.

Comment: @FabianBorg I do not understand what you are doing with your formula or edit.  Your formula will return an array of two values; and your edit does not show any row or column labels; nor, even if it started in A1, would I be able to understand how that formula would produce a "monthly calculation". Also, there is no way for me to get a screenshot into an Excel sheet without laboriously copying it by hand. Please read Help for [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have been at this for a month now, but I am still not able to solve how to calculate the monthly totals as the negative values are not being calculated. I am attaching a link to the spreadsheet here https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B1AA59DC4854E3D8!395156&authkey=!ADq6XwSFqG6lLWg&ithint=file%2cxlsx

Comment: @FabianBorg  That was not your original question.  But, if I understand what you are trying to do, your formula should probably be `O9: =ABS(SUM($L$9:L9-$M$9:M9))`, entered as an array formula by holding down `ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter`.  Then fill down.  And the cells number format will need to be `[h]:mm`.  The brackets around the `h` ensure it will not roll over after 24 hours.  You'll also need to add the conditional formatting as above, with that same format.  You will NOT be able to have a negative number in that cell, in a time format, using the 1900 date system.

Comment: @FabianBorg To expand on my previous comment, although the cell will not be able to **contain** a negative value, the CF rule will allow it to **display** the negative value.

Comment: Ron, I tried your suggestion but it as the negative value shows up positive, it would send the monthly total with a wrong summation. The monthly totals are need to compliment the conditional formatting your good self suggested. The totals would be drawn up at the end of each month (pay period).

Comment: @FabianBorg. Clarify your new problem.

Comment: Ron my question is how can I sum the results of the conditional formatting on a monthly bases where the negative values are deducted and not added up.

Comment: @FabianBorg You cannot.  You have to sum from the original data as I showed in my suggested formula in my comment above.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no really good way to do this in Excel.  The best I have found if you want to keep the numeric time value and can't use 1904 dates is to use a custom number format like the following:

```
hh:mm;-[m]" mins"
```

This displays positive times normally and negative times as a number of minutes.  So +1:45 will display as `01:45` and -1:45 will display as `-105 mins`.  Or for consistency you could just go for:

```
[m]" mins"
```

Which formats everything as minutes.

This works because the "elapsed time" formats (`[h]`, `[m]`, and `[s]`) do handle negative times.  Unfortunately you can't have more than one in a format, and `[h]:mm` just triggers the hash signs again.

Comment: I like that solution, so long as an output in minutes is acceptable.